# Validating the data type of a column in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have pyspark dataframe with 3 columns. 
DDL of the hive table 'test1' is all having string data types.
So if I do df.printSchema all are string data type as shown below,

```
>>> df = spark.sql("select * from default.test1")
>>> df.printSchema()                                                                                                                                                                     
root                                                                                                                                                                                       
 |-- c1: string (nullable = true)                                                                                                                                            
 |-- c2: string (nullable = true)                                                                                                                                        
 |-- c3: string (nullable = true)  

+----------+--------------+-------------------+                                                                                                                 
|c1        |c2            |c3                 |                                                                                                                 
+----------+--------------+-------------------+                                                                                                                 
|April     |20132014      |4                  |                                                                                                                 
|May       |20132014      |5                  |                                                                                                                 
|June      |abcdefgh      |6                  |                                                                                                                 
+----------+--------------+-------------------+
```

Now I want to filter only those records which are of integer type in 'c2' column.
So basically I need only first 2 records which are integer type like '20132014'. And exclude the other records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one line:

```
df.withColumn("c2", df["c2"].cast("integer")).na.drop(subset=["c2"])
```

If `c2` is not a valid integer, it will be `NULL` and dropped in the subsequent step.

Without changing the type

```
valid = df.where(df["c2"].cast("integer").isNotNull())
invalid = df.where(df["c2"].cast("integer").isNull())
```